# Putting own javascript in selected page

Tags: javascript

I want to know, if it is possible and how to run javascript code in console in new page, when somebody click on link in my page.

For example. I have got page and there is button. When somebody click on it, it will redirect to another page. In this page It will run my own javascript code, sended from previous page and appeared in console of new page.

This way I want to change for example stylesheet of some selected page and demonstrate the changes.

Thank you.

Comment: you can use web storage to save you js that you want to run in next page and then run in next page by using eval, but this is not recommended.

Comment: Why can't you just emit the JavaScript on "the next page"?

Answer (score 1):

Shortest answer: **No**.

Short answer:

This would effectively violate the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), and would be a nightmare as far as [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) is concerned.

Imagine for a moment that someone created an 'infected' link, when clicked would infect all the links on the next page in the same manner. Eventually when on the correct page, these infected links would run some code that would snatch up details of what was occurring inside the page (keystrokes, clicks, etc...) and send it back to a server.

All this without ever touching the user's machine.

---

The closest thing you can do is create a bookmarklet or userscript. It's up to the user to place these things on their computer, and run them on the correct page.